Using combinatorial methods to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{m}{k}=m\binom{n+1}{m}$
Earlier today I derived that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{m}{k}=m\binom{n+1}{m}$ using complex analysis and the contour integral formula for the binomial coefficient, but now I am wondering if there is a purely combinatorial proof of this result, or any result using basic algebra and no calculus/complex analysis methods. The $(-1)^{m-k}$ suggest it might has to do with principle of inclusion/exclusion, but I have no idea how to begin.

Isn't that just telescoping? If so, then sure

Here's a purely combinatorial argument. Let $A=\{1,2,\dots, m,\cdots, n+m\}$ be a set of $n+m$ elements. Let us count in how many ways we can form subsets of size $m$ with numbers only in $\{m, m+1, \dots, n+m\}$.
First the hard way. Let $k\in\{1,2,\dots, m-1\}$ and let $A_k$ be the collection of subsets of $S$ of size $m$ such that $k\in S$. This can be achieved by throwing in $k$ first and then choosing the rest of the elements, which gives a total of $$|A_k|=\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$$ and there are $m-1$ such sets, one for every $k$. Analogously, we have $$\bigg|\bigcap_{i=1}^jA_{k_i}\bigg|=\binom{n+m-j}{m-j}$$ and there are $\binom{m-1}{j}$ such sets, one for every choice of $(k_1, k_2,\dots, k_j)$. The inclusion exclusion principle now says $$\bigg|A\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{m-1}A_i\bigg|=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\binom{m-1}{j}\binom{n+m-j}{m-j}$$
Let us massage this expression a little. We have \begin{align*}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\binom{m-1}{j}\binom{n+m-j}{m-j}&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}\color{red}{\binom{m-1}{m-k}}\binom{n+k}{k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}\color{blue}{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}\binom{n+k}{k}\\&=\sum_{\color{red}{k=1}}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}\frac{\color{blue}{k}}{\color{red}{m}}\color{blue}{\binom{m}{k}}\binom{n+k}{k}\\&=\color{blue}{\frac1m}\sum_{\color{blue}{k=0}}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\end{align*} where we reindexed in the first equality by $j\to m-k$.
Now we count this directly. It is just $\binom{n+m-(m-1)}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m}$ and thus we have $${\frac1m}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+1}{m}$$ Sending the $m$ to the other side finishes the proof.

This is great. Quick remark: When looking for things like this, do the re-indexing of the sum first. ie it is probably going to be more natural to have it written as a sum from 0 to $m$ before you notice what the next steps are to recognise it as I-E principle. But also: This makes me wonder if there is an even more direct counting proof in which the re-indexing is the only algebra necessary…

Here is an elementary derivation based upon the Chu-Vandermonde identity. We obtain
\begin{align*}\
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^m}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{m}{k}}\\
&=m(-1)^m\sum_{k=1}^m\binom{-n-1}{k}\binom{m-1}{k-1}\tag{1}\\
&=m(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{-n-1}{k}\binom{m-1}{m-k}\\
&=m(-1)^m\binom{m-n-2}{m}\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=m\binom{n+1}{m}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.
Comment

In (1) and (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$. We also use $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.

In (2) we use the Chu-Vandermonde identity.



I have found a way to solve by generating function of convolution.
$$T_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{m}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-k}k\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{m}{m-k}.$$
The sum $T_m$ is the coefficient $x^m$ of function $f(x)g(x)$, where $$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}x^k=(1-x)^m,$$ $$g(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}k\binom{n+k}{k}x^k,$$
$g(x)$ is quite complicated than $f(x)$. We have $\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{c+k-1}{k}x^k=1/(1-x)^c$, we can derive $$g(x)=x\sum_{k\ge 0}k\binom{n+k}{k}x^{k-1}=x\Big(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}\Big)'=(n+1)\frac{x}{(1-x)^{n+2}}.$$
Thus, \begin{align}T_m&=[x^m]f(x)g(x)\\&=[x^m](n+1)x(1-x)^{m-n-2}\\&=(n+1)(-1)^{m-1}\binom{m-n-2}{m-1}\\&=(n+1)\binom{n}{m-1}\\&=m\binom{n+1}{m}.\end{align}
My proof implicitly use the following formula $$\binom{r}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k-r-1}{k}.$$
